# This code error - too few arguments to function 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Hello I'm new to coding & made the code but there's this error saying:
**too few arguments to function 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'.** Did I do it wrong or is it something else?

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>

Servo Servo1;
Servo Servo2;

void setup() {
  Servo2.attach(9);
  Servo1.attach(10);
  pinMode(5, INPUT); //IR 1
  pinMode(4, INPUT); //IR 2
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); //Standby LED#1 
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT); //Standby LED#2
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalWrite(4) == HIGH) {
    Servo1.write(60);
    delay(1000);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalWrite(5) == HIGH) {
    Servo2.write(60);
    delay(1000);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Comment: can we see the `digitalWrite` function?

Comment: @Steven, it is a standard function on Arduino and Processing

Comment: Read your compiler's errors and warnings before asking a question.  The most basic arduino tutorial would make the most glaring errors in your code obvious.  First, it must compile without warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digitalWrite argument requires both the pin to write to and the value to set the pin to. Your statement,

```
if (digitalWrite(4) == HIGH)
```

should probably be

```
if (digitalRead(4) == HIGH)
```

It looks like you should be using `digitalRead` instead of `digitalWrite` when reading from a GPIO. See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/35965 for more info

Comment: thank you everyone for your answers. it really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code.

Let's begin with the most obvious. You cannot have multiple loop functions.

Arduino will call `setup()` and then call `loop()` over and over in an infinite loop.

The compiler should raise an error for redefining loop.

The second issue is the one you're asking about.

`digitalWrite` can be used to

- set the logic state of a pin, if the pin is configured as OUTPUT
- enable/disable the internal pullup resistor if the pin is configured as INPUT

You did the following:

```
 if(digitalWrite(4)== HIGH)
```

So you

- you provided to few arguments to digitalWrite. It expects a pin number and a value (HIGH or LOW)
- you use it in an if statement although it does not return any value

As pin 4 is configured as input you probably wanted to use `digitalRead` to read its state.

use `if (digitalRead(4) == HIGH)` or simply `if(digitalRead(4))`

Please read https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/DigitalPins and the rest of the Arduino manual